# Get data from 2 tables and insert into another

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help..

I am I trying to retrieve data from two tables and insert into another using php +mysql, but it doesn't work. It shows me this message (Query got problem).

This is my code:

```
$emp_id = $_SESSION['emp_id'];

$from= "select department.name from department,employee where emp_id='$emp_id' and department.dept_id = employee.dept_id ";
$result_form = mysql_query($from);

$dept_from = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_form);
$dept_name = $dept_from['department.name'];
```

$query = "INSERT INTO Student (date, description, from, emp_id, to)

VALUES

(now(),'$_POST[description]','$dept_name','$emp_id','$_POST[to]')";

```
$result = mysql_query($query);                                          
if(!$result)
    {die("Query got problem").(mysql_error());}
else{
```

Comment: I see 2 reserved words in the insert query use backticks for them `to` `from`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Your mysql query in not proper use like given below:

```
    $emp_id = $_SESSION['emp_id'];    

    $from= "SELECT d.name FROM department d LEFT JOIN employee e ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id' ";

    $result_form = mysql_query($from);
    $dept_from = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_form);
    $dept_name = $dept_from['name'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO Student (`date`, `description`, `from`, `emp_id`, `to`) VALUES (now(),'".$_POST[description]."','".$dept_name."','".$emp_id."','".$_POST[to]."')"; 

   $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you for your help but nothing change

Comment: echo $query; variable, run the query in mysql & check what is the problem ?

Comment: It shows this message:                                           INSERT INTO Student (date, description, from, emp_id, to) VALUES (now(),'this is my Reason... ','','','HR')Query got problem

Comment: That means you didn't get data from previous query. echo $from and check data.

Comment: It shows                                                              INSERT INTO Student (date, description, from, emp_id, to) VALUES (now(),'this is my Reason... ','','1','HR')Resource id #3Query got problem

Comment: Why you don't get value of $dept_name ??

Comment: I don't know what is the problem

Comment: this is the last result                                                      INSERT INTO Student (date, description, from, emp_id, to) VALUES (now(),'this is my Reason... ','IT','1','HR')Resource id #3Query got problem

Comment: I put    echo $dept_name;                                                               INSERT INTO Student (date, description, from, emp_id, to) VALUES (now(),'this is my Reason... ','IT','1','HR')ITQuery got problem

Comment: I think the problem is the date

Comment: Working Now or Not ??

Comment: It is working now.                                                    Thank you very much.                                                        thank you for your effort and your time

Answer (score 0):

Backticks might do the trick here.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Student (`date`, `description`, `from`, `emp_id`, `to`)
    VALUES
(now(),'$_POST[description]','$dept_name','$emp_id','$_POST[to]')";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO Student (date, description, from, emp_id, to)

        VALUES

    (now(),' " . $_POST['description'] ."','$dept_name','$emp_id','". $_POST['to']. "')";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code below

```
$emp_id = 1;

$from= "select department.name from test.department,test.employee where emp_id='$emp_id' and department.dept_id = employee.dept_id ";
$result_form = mysql_query($from);
$dept_from = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_form);

$dept_name      = $dept_from['name'];
$date           = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$description    = isset($_POST[description])?$_POST[description]:"none";
$to             = isset($_POST[to])?$_POST[to]:"none";

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `test`.`test`
                    (`date`,
                    `description`,
                    `from`,
                    `emp_id`,
                    `to`)
                    VALUES
                    (
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s'
                    );
                    ",
                    $date,$description,$dept_name,$emp_id,$to); 


$result = mysql_query($query);   

if(!$result)
    {
        die("Query got problem").(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but nothing change.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you very much. thank you for your effort and your time.